# Extending or passing as argument

Tags: java, class

Which one is a better practice, doing something like this

```
public class A {
    private B b;

    public A() {
         b = new B(this);
    }
}

public class B {
    private A a;

    public B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

or extending the class, im really confused about the difference besides having 'a' as a field.

Comment: it's no good, think me an example with real objects

Comment: use extends when A is a kind of B. like Cat is an animal. so  Cat extends Animal.

Comment: General opinion these days is to *prefer composition over inheritance*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on particular situation.

Lets assume that **A** class represents a `Car`, then 
  if **B** is an `Engine`  then you should use a composition (Car has an Engine)
  if **B** is a `RaceCar`  then you should use an inheritance (RaceCar is a better Car)

If in doubt, current trend in software development is to prefer composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

- **Inheritance**: Apply the **IS-A** test.
- **composition** : Apply the **HAS-A** relationship.,

Answer (score 0):

it depends what are you going to achieve.
Just like Win.ubuntu said use extends in case cat/animal.
But if you want to have something like car has an engine then use your second example.